# Mouse only working over usb 3 port?

Tags: usb, mouse

I usually connect my mouse to a USB 2 port, but after hibernation I can only use the mouse from the USB 3 port.
`xface list` and `lsusb` don't show the mouse as present when connecting to any of the USB 2 ports, but do if it's the USB 3 port.

The USB 2 ports seem to work fine for other stuff like flash drives.

Is there a way to reset the USB controller (without restarting the computer) or any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I use  [usbreset](https://gist.github.com/x2q/5124616)

```
which usbreset
/usr/local/bin/usbreset
```

Comment: This would reset a device. My problem is that it's not detected at all on USB 2 ports until I restart the laptop, so I have to find a way to restart the USB controller.